# How can I have a class where data members can be parameterized by definitions in different namespace?

Tags: c++, c++20

I am trying to move a bunch of functions that are all related into a class (where they are all static) just so the class acts as a nice wrapper around them (where I can specify the interface, and make the helper functions private, etc).

So I created a class bigint_to_string, where I put all these functions inside.  But then I realized that there is a bunch of things I want to be able to make configurable, such as the type of the container (which I could use a template for), but there are other parameters that may/may not derive from the type.  The class (functions) behavior is the same regardless of which flavor I choose, as long as all the parameters are tightly coupled.  My initial approach was to move the parameters out into namespaces for now, as follows:

### 4bits

```
  namespace _4bits { // 4 bits -> 0xF per bucket                                                                                                                                             
      constexpr uint8_t BUCKET_BITS{4}; // 4 bits                                                                                                                                            
      using BASE_TYPE = uint8_t;                                                                                                                                                             
      constexpr bool LEFT_SHIFT_HI_BIT_DOES_NOT_OVERFLOW{sizeof(BASE_TYPE)*CHAR_BIT > BUCKET_BITS};                                                                                          
      using CONTAINER = std::vector<BASE_TYPE>;                                                                                                                                              
      constexpr BASE_TYPE MAX{0xF}; // 2**4-1 == 15                                                                                                                                          
      //const auto hi_bit_set = BASE_TYPE(1) << (sizeof(BASE_TYPE) * BITS - 1);                                                                                                              
      constexpr BASE_TYPE hi_bit_set = BASE_TYPE(1) << (BUCKET_BITS - 1); // 0x8 or 0b1000
}
```

### 8bits

```
namespace _8bits { // 8 bits -> 0xFF per bucket                                                                                                                                            
      constexpr uint8_t BUCKET_BITS{8}; // 8 bits                                                                                                                                            
      using BASE_TYPE = uint8_t;                                                                                                                                                             
      constexpr bool LEFT_SHIFT_HI_BIT_DOES_NOT_OVERFLOW{sizeof(BASE_TYPE)*CHAR_BIT > BUCKET_BITS};                                                                                          
      using CONTAINER = std::vector<BASE_TYPE>;                                                                                                                                              
      constexpr BASE_TYPE MAX{0xFF}; // 2**8-1 == 255                                                                                                                                        
      constexpr BASE_TYPE hi_bit_set = BASE_TYPE(1) << (BUCKET_BITS - 1); // 0x80 or 0b10000000                                                                                              
}
```

I would like to be able to select which types I want to use, something like:

````
  // selection
  using BASE_TYPE = _4bits::BASE_TYPE;
  using CONTAINER = _4bits::CONTAINER;
  constexpr auto MAX = _4bits::MAX;
  constexpr auto hi_bit_set = _4bits::hi_bit_set;                                                                                                                                            
  constexpr bool cannot_overflow = _4bits::LEFT_SHIFT_HI_BIT_DOES_NOT_OVERFLOW;```
````

But inside a class that is just a wrapper to a bunch of functions:

```
class bigint_to_string {
    // selection                                                                                                                                                                           
    using BASE_TYPE = _4bits::BASE_TYPE;                                                                                                                                                   
    using CONTAINER = _4bits::CONTAINER;                                                                                                                                                   
    static constexpr decltype(_4bits::BUCKET_BITS) BUCKET_BITS = _4bits::BUCKET_BITS;                                                                                                      
    static constexpr auto MAX = _4bits::MAX;                                                                                                                                               
    static constexpr auto hi_bit_set = _4bits::hi_bit_set;                                                                                                                                 
    static constexpr bool cannot_overflow = _4bits::LEFT_SHIFT_HI_BIT_DOES_NOT_OVERFLOW;                                                                                                   

private: // the class is just a wrapper to a bunch of functions, I don't want to allow objects
    bigint_to_string(const bigint_to_string&) = delete;                                                                                                                                    
    bigint_to_string(bigint_to_string&&) = delete;                                                                                                                                         
    bigint_to_string& operator=(const bigint_to_string&) = delete;                                                                                                                         
    bigint_to_string& operator=(bigint_to_string&&) = delete;                                                                                                                              
    virtual ~bigint_to_string() = delete;                                                                                                                                                  

public: // access interface
    static std::string get_decimal(CONTAINER bigint)
    using CONTAINER = std::vector<BASE_TYPE>;

private: // internal helper methods
    static bool is_zero(CONTAINER& bigint);                                                                                                                                                                                             
    static void canonize(CONTAINER& bigint);
    static void divide_by_2(CONTAINER& bigint)
    static void multiply_by_2(CONTAINER& bigint)
    static int cmp(const CONTAINER& a, const CONTAINER& b)
    static void set_bit_at(CONTAINER& bigint, std::size_t index, bool set=true)
    static CONTAINER divide(CONTAINER& n, CONTAINER d)
};
```

One idea I had was to convert the namespace to a struct, and pass that as a type:

```
struct Types{};
struct _4bits : Types {...};
struct _8bits : Types {...};

template <Types>
class bigint_to_string {...};
```

But that won't work... I don't want to parameterize every single of these options as template parameters, and then create "macros" or such for each "bundle", I would really prefer to have these in a namespace or structure and then pass it all at once to the class. Is it possible?

Comment: "But that won't work..." why not? Swap a namespace with functions to a type with static member functions and pass in the type. What about that does not work?

Comment: I am not sure I understand... I tried to do that, but how do I pass it to the class? 
template <Types types> class bigint {}; // ?

I am not sure how to actually pass the structure as a non-type parameter to the class